# React: The `value` prop supplied to <select> must be a scalar value if `multiple` is false

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux-form

I am getting this warning:

> Warning: The `value` prop supplied to  must be a scalar value
> if `multiple` is false. Check the render method of `Control`.

I am using the React Redux Form https://davidkpiano.github.io/react-redux-form/docs/api/Control.html#prop-defaultValue.

The data is coming in as an array of objects to display inside of the select options element. I don't want to turn the control into a multiple since we only want the user to select one value.

How would I go about solving this warning?

Comment: Did you solve this warning?

Comment: @PavelKrizhanovskiy - No I have not solved this yet :/

Comment: im also unable to solve it, and i wonder if its because in value im giving it the key of an object, which is still a string, such as objVar.name but still... this warning pops up, though the form works fine

Answer (score 12, accepted):

if you use an array in your state it will get that error if you are not doing multiple searches

if it is a simple search use single quotes ''

in **useState('')**

```
const [categoria, setCategoria] = useState('')

<select
        onChange={e => setCategoria(e.target.value)}
        value={categoria}
       >
</select>
```

Comment: Solved my problem! I had my useState using an array for some reason

Comment: thanks solved my problem

Answer (score 12):

If you specify

```
multiple={false}
```

Then whatever you provide on the `select` as a value must be a single value, like "apple".

However, if you specify

```
multiple={true}
```

react expects an array:

```
value={['apple','orange']}
```

See the example of a select with multiple={true} in [the official documentation for React Forms](https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html).

Bear in mind that react will only add the `multiple` keyword to the rendered html if you set it to true.  So your control can have a `multiple` property set to false and not create a rendered element with multi-select.

Comment: Whenever I used multiple={true} it seems as though the options are visible as if looking from a text area instead of having the dropdown options with a scroll method.  Has anyone ever run into this problem?

Comment: @DavidHahn  If you inspect the generated HTML, what actual element is being created?  Maybe a styling issue?

Comment: thanks for following up JE. I realized I had an extra jsx tag rendering above the previously nested data in code.

Answer (score 3):

I was getting this error even after value was array, was able to solve by following

```
value={value || []}
```