# How can I make select and option happen with useState?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

1. Create a drop-down component from Breeds that allows you to select a breed.

   - The component name is BreedsSelect component (BreedsSelect.js)
   - Use select and option tags.
   - The BreedsSelect component should be passed the breeds (an array of the list of breeds) as props. The variable name to be assigned should also be "breeds".
     Example: `<BreedsSelect breeds={breeds} />`
2. Load the BreedsSelect component from the DogListContainer component.
3. Define selectedBreed and setSelectedBreed in useState to hold the selected breed. (Define them in the DogListContainer component.
4. Reflect the selected breed information in selectedBreed on drop-down selection.

   - Update state on dropdown selection (add props to BreedsSelect that you may need).
   - Use the data in selectedBreed for the value of the select tag. (Let's add the props we might need to BreedsSelect)

How would I change these two codes to accomplish these four things?

---

BreedsSelect.js:

```
import { useState } from 'react'
export const BreedsSelect = props => {
  const [selectedBreed, setSelectedBreed] = useState(null)
  return (
    <div>
      <select value={selectedBreed}>
        <option></option>
        <option></option>
        <opition></opition>
      </select>
    </div>
  )
}
```

DogListContainer.js:

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react' // DO NOT DELETE
import { BreedsSelect } from './BreedsSelect'
export const DogListContainer = () => {
  const [breeds, setBreeds] = useState(null)
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('https://dog.ceo/api/breeds/list/all')
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => {
        console.log(data.message)
        setBreeds(data.message)
      })
  }, [])
  return <BreedsSelect breeds={breeds} />
}
```

Comment: (1) Your `<select>` element is not setting the updated `selectedBreed` when an `input` event is fired, and (2) it's not clear how both of your components interact with each other.

Answer (score 0):

```js
import { useState } from 'react'
export const BreedsSelect = props => {
  const [selectedBreed, setSelectedBreed] = useState(null)
  
  const options = props.breeds
  
  return (
    <div>
      <select value={selectedBreed} onChange={(e) => setSelectedBreed(e.target.value)}>
        {options.map(breed => {
          <option>{breed}</option>
        })}
      </select>
    </div>
  )
}
```

1. Map over the breeds array to return each option as an  tag
2. Use the onChange event listener to set the value of the select to the selected option

Comment: I get an error "Cannot read properties of null (reading 'map')".

Comment: Using `options?.map` should fix that - @fdsfsd

Comment: Iget an err "options.map is not a function".

Comment: You’re passing in ‘null’ as the staring state. You can fix this issue with replacing the bill with an empty array. Like this - const [selectedBreed, setSelectedBreed] = useState([]);

Answer (score 0):

You can render multiple options by mapping over your `breeds` array. The initial value of `selectedBreed` should be a string to prevent an error if the `multiple` prop is false, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47721427/react-the-value-prop-supplied-to-select-must-be-a-scalar-value-if-multiple) SO answer for more information.

With the `handleSelectChange` you can update your state if you select a different option.

BreedsSelect.js:

```js
const BreedsSelect = ({ breeds }) => {
  const [selectedBreed, setSelectedBreed] = useState("");

  const handleSelectChange = (e) => {
    setSelectedBreed(e.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <select value={selectedBreed} onChange={handleSelectChange}>
        {breeds.map((breed) => (
          <option key={breed}>{breed}</option>
        ))}
      </select>
    </div>
  );
};
```

In your list component you should change the `breeds` initial state to an empty array, this will prevent errors saying that you can't map over `breeds` in the `BreedsSelect` component.

DogListContainer.js:

```js
...
const [breeds, setBreeds] = useState([])
...
```